# Controller parameter is undefined in my directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do something very simple, using the controller parameter of the link function for my directive, but it's being passed as 'undefined'.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

The HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl" my-form >
            <p> Click count: {{ count }} </p>               
        </div>  
    </div>
```

The Javascript:

```
myApp.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope){    
    $scope.count = 0;

    this.init = function(val) {
        $scope.count = val;
    }   
});


myApp.directive('myForm', function() {    
    var linkFn = function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        ctrl.init(17); //Error here.  ctrl is undefined

        elem.bind('click', function() {
            scope.$apply(function(){                
                scope.count++;
            });
        });     
    };

    return linkFn;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my directive has to use the Directive Definition Object to return the link function and include a reference to the Controller as the 'controller' parameter of the ddo, like so:

```
myApp.directive('myForm', function() {

    var linkFn = function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        ctrl.init("17"); //This now works, due to my return below


        elem.bind('click', function() {
            scope.$apply(function(){                
                scope.count++;
            });
        });     
    };

    return {
        controller: 'SampleCtrl',
        link:linkFn};
});
```

Comment: Interesting, this isn't mentioned here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms The angular dev team apparently does not use this pattern (even though it might be necessary).

Comment: Why in the world should a directive have to have any direct reference to a particular controller? Aren't they supposed to be nice and portable?

Answer (score 2):

As Dan correctly askes in his comment on the accepted answer

> Why in the world should a directive have to have any direct reference
>   to a particular controller? Aren't they supposed to be nice and
>   portable?

You not need to reference a controller to leverage the `ctrl` parameter in a directive.

Instead you can use `require: 'ngModel'`

As the model will be defined inside a ng-controller scope value this creates your link to the controller without having to hard code the controller name.

Here's an exampled based off of a directive I use to set a form as invalid if an input file is too large.

```
myApp.directive('maxFileSize', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var maxSize = Number(attrs.maxFileSize);

            var sizeHandler = function () {
                if (element.get(0).files.length) {
                    var fileSize = element.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
                    if (fileSize > maxSize) {
                        //console.log('file size is more than ' + maxSize + ' bytes!');

                        ctrl.$setValidity("fileSize", false);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity("fileSize", true);
                    }
                }
            };

            element.bind('change', sizeHandler);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to work off the controller, could you work of the scope like I have done in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eLeV0otcmmp8REBoQ7PH?p=preview)?

Comment: I could, that would certainly work, but I'm trying to get the controller parameter working.  I would like to actually do quite a bit more than I'm demonstrating here, this is just the simplest example I could put together quickly.

Comment: Cool, I'll have another go at it then. That was just the simplest possible way I could think to get your actual code to work.